# Can't cast or convert from int to Integer and can't instantiate Integer within a method override

Tags: java

The following is at the scope of a public class

```
private class WrapperMap<K, Integer> extends HashMap<K, Integer>{
    @Override
    public Integer get(Object key){
        if (super.containsKey(key))
            return super.get(key);
        else{
            return new Integer(1);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried a lot of things to return the Integer object 1 in the else block, but nothing seems to work. Why not?

`return new Integer(1);` leads to `Cannot instantiate the type Integer`
`return Integer.valueOf(1)` leads to `The method valueOf(int) is undefined for the type Integer`
`return 1` leads to `Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Integer`
`return (Integer)1;` leads to `Cannot cast from int to Integer`

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking. For starters, your `key` is defined as type `Object`, but the `HashMap` it's derived from wants a `K`.

Comment: I get compile time error when trying to return an Integer with value 1 in the else block. I tried (Integer)1, 1, new Integer(1), etc. but everything gives me compile-time errors. If I put K in the arg, it doesn't override. The original method wants an Object.

Comment: **What** compile-time error?

Comment: Post the actual error message.

Comment: Are you sure you are using java.lang.Integer in your code? The kind of exceptions you are posting don't seem to say that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Friend.. Try this:

```
private class WrapperMap<K> extends HashMap<K, Integer>{
@Override
public Integer get(Object key){
    if (super.containsKey(key))
        return super.get(key);
    else{
        return 1;
    }
}
}
```

You don't need two generics variable for `WrapperMap`.
`Integer` in `WrapperMap<K, Integer>` is considered as a type-variable.
Since the second type-variable `S` of `HashMap<K,S>` is fixed as `Integer`, `WrapperMap<K>` is enough.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just "return 1" instead "return new Integer(1)" that will be autoboxed and keep the same return type.

Like this.

```
public Integer get(Object key){
        if (super.containsKey(key))
            return super.get(key);
        else{
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have specified `Integer` as a type parameter, and it's shadowing the `java.lang.Integer` class you want. Since your class only works with `Integer`s, remove it as a parameter (leave it on the `HashMap`), and your code should work correctly.